# Understand inconsistent results between direct effect of mediation analysis and linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, mediation, jasp

I have a question concerning different results between linear regression and the direct effect of mediation analysis.
Indeed, linear regression between predictor X and outcome Y showed a non-significant relationship. However, when I add a mediator within a mediation analysis, the direct effect between X and Y is significant (Indirect and total effects are non-significant). How can I interpret that?
I compute this analysis on JASP.
Thanks